# Is it possible to export a half image out of the full image

Tags: sql-server

I have saved the image in a `varbinary` datatype using the `openrowset` method in the column of my table. And I am able to export that image from the table to my desired location. But I want to export only half image from that image - is that possible?

I have copied the code from the following site

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4963/simple-image-import-and-export-using-tsql-for-sql-server/

I thought if I reduce the `varbinary` data of the image to the half of its actual data then maybe I can export the half size of the image but I don't know how can I do that.

Comment: May we ask what possible use half of an image would be?  And, do you just mean the first half of the bytes in that column, or some other logical meaning which might be dependent on a particular image format?

Comment: Actually it's my task to reduce the size of the image... m actually practising sql server .... nd yes thats wht i mean to keep only the first half of the bytes in that column

Comment: To reduce the size of an image **and** maintain the same image requires complex code. If you just remove half the bytes its unlikely you'll have an image at all. I certainly wouldn't attempt it on SQL Server except maybe within a CLR procedure. This would normally be carried out in the front end code.

Comment: Leaving out half the data will produce either a corrupt image, or only the top half of the image, or (if you're really lucky) an image with about half the detail of the original, if it uses a progressive encoding scheme. In general, you can't rely on a simple relationship between the number of bytes and the image, so you can't meaningfully process an image in T-SQL alone. A client tool like ImageMagick could do so, and you could even invoke those directly from SQL Server, but I wouldn't recommend that either -- instead, have client code fetch the whole image and then process it.

Comment: You need to scale the image - tsql has no functionality to do that.